# Send an ephemeral message to person who clicked button

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to show buttons on a message, but only allow the original requester of the message to interact with the buttons. If anybody else clicks the buttons then I want to send them a secret message telling them that their click was ignored.

I've been looking into this for a while and I keep finding people saying that it's not possible, but yet the Dank Memer bot already does exactly this! If you click a button on somebody else's message then the bot will send you a message saying "This menu is not for you." and it will say "Only you can see this message"

Currently I have this code

```
const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: "BUTTON", time: 15000});

collector.on("collect",collected => {
    if(collected.user.id !== interaction.user.id){
        //collected.member.send("This command is being controlled by somebody else.");
        // What can I put in here to send an ephemeral message to collected.user?? I can send them a DM using .send(), but that's not what I want.
        return;
    }
    if(collected.customId === "confirm"){
        interaction.followUp("Success");
    }else{
        interaction.followUp("Ignore");
    }
});
```

Here's a picture of Dank Memer doing it... Which leads me to believe it's possible. (He said this in response to me asking for a leaderboard on one account and then trying to navigate it on a different account.)

[image: Dank Memer doing what I've been told is impossible]

Please tell me how this is done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-component-collector) example from the discord.js guide you are able to do this by replying to the [collected](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/InteractionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect) object as it represents an interaction:

```
collector.on("collect",collected => {
    // Replies to the user who clicked a button that wasn't theirs
    if(collected.user.id !== interaction.user.id){
        collected.reply({ content: `These buttons aren't for you!`, ephemeral: true })
        return;
    }
    if(collected.customId === "confirm"){
        interaction.followUp("Success");
    } else {
        interaction.followUp("Ignore");
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I tried this out before, but I must have accidentally made a typo when I did because every time I ran my code the program would terminate with no error message, so I just assumed it wasn't possible. I just re-wrote it again from the ground up and now it works perfectly. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make your reply `ephemeral` you have to use [`interaction.reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.1/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) and get such code:

```js
interaction.reply({ content: `text`, ephemeral: true })
```

Comment: No! I'm sorry, but this is not the correct answer. Using `interaction.reply()` sends the secret message to the original command user, which is _not_ the person who should be receiving it! I want to send the message to the person trying to interact with the command, not the person who originally executed it. I've used that exact code and I'm certain that it doesn't work properly.